# Report Designer

Tags: reporting, angularjs, react, asp.net

I am designing a Fleet Management system, It is a Web Application that will run on browsers and tablets, and phones.

Now the Application will have to generate a lot of PDF reports, (e.g number of vehicles in the Yard, Generate Invoices for Hired Vehicles etc) and they will be done Dynamically, one a user presses download report button and some will automatically be sent by email.

I have seen companies like Avis have this features where you sign a rental agreement then seconds later it get sent as a PDF file to the email address via email and is that logos and my signature on it.

What library are they using?

I am looking for a library that can generate PDF report with charts, tables, picture etc

I am deigning my app using `asp.net` core but any `js` libraries like `Angular`, `react`  are also welcome

the Library can be Open Source (What i am Hoping for) or Licensed (If I don't find the right one).

I saw [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/) and it is really good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Syncfusion Report Platform](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/reportr) can be used to display and create/edit Reports in JS/React applications with a .NET/Core backend: [Live Sample](https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/reportdesigner/defaultfunctionalities).

[React Sample Code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ReactJS-1965081000.zip).

[image: Report Designer]

Reports can be exported to Word, Excel, PDF, PowerPoint and HTML.

Reports are serialized in [Report Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_Definition_Language) and can be created using the Report Designer (desktop or web) and the designer can be embedded in your application.

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Just out of curiosity big companies use Syncfusion and others for report generation right. There is no open source reporting tool you know that can do this kinds of things